# JavaScript HTML - Extra required form fields appearing on user select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a form where, if the user selects 'yes' from a dropdown, two extra fields appear. Both of these fields are required, and one of them needs to be validated according to an array of 'codes' - the user must input one of the codes in the array for the form to submit correctly. However, if the user selects 'no' from the dropdown, these fields do not appear and are not required, and the array validation does *not* occur and the form can be submitted.

I have some code for this, however I can't get the fields to appear. An earlier issue I encountered with this (minus the array validation - including that broke the code and stopped the extra fields appearing) was that if the user selected 'yes', and then went back to change their mind and selected 'no', then the form would not submit, clearly still requiring the fields to be filled in/correct array value inputted.

If anyone could help me in making this work I would greatly appreciate it.

HTML:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="action.php">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Defect?</label>
    <select onclick='checkIfYes()' class="select form-control" id="defect" name="defect">
      <option id="No" value="No">No</option>
      <option id="Yes" value="Yes">Yes</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="extra" name="extra" style="display: none">

    <label class="control-label" for="desc">Description</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="desc" name="desc" required disabled>

    <label class="control-label" for="auth_by">Authorised By</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="auth_code_input" name="auth_by" required disabled>

  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">Submit
    </button>
  </div>

</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

   checkIfYes = function checkIfYes() {
        if (document.getElementById('defect').value == 'Yes') {

          // show extra fields & make them required
          document.getElementById('extra').style.display = '';
          document.getElementById('auth_code_input').disabled = false;
          document.getElementById('desc').disabled = false;

          // show user if their input is one of the codes in the array when leaving field
          $('#auth_code_input').blur(function() {
            if (!ValidateInput()) {
              e.preventDefault();
            }
          });
          // prevent form submission if input is not one of the codes in the array
          $('#auth_form').on('submit', function(e) {
            if (!ValidateInput()) {
              e.preventDefault();
            }
          });

          function ValidateInput() {
            var codes = ['Foo', 'Bar']; // user must enter one of these
            var IsValid = false;
            var input = $('#auth_code_input').val()

            if (codes.indexOf(input) > -1) { // if input equals one of the codes in the array
              $('#iconBad').removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
              IsValid = true;
            } else {
              $('#iconBad').removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
              IsValid = false;
            }

            return IsValid;
          }

        } else { // hide and disable extra fields so form can submit
          document.getElementById('extra').style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementById('auth_code_input').disabled = true;
          document.getElementById('desc').disabled = true;
        }
      }
    });
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sinesine/z6Lm1m5x/23/)**

Comment: Doesn't work in the fiddle. You have to change the line function checkIfYes() to checkIfYes = function checkIfYes() -- Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/z6Lm1m5x/24/

Comment: I'm still having the issue where if the user selects 'yes' but then changes to 'no' it does not allow the form to submit.

Comment: Yeah, the validation is getting clobbered because it's currently defined inside your checkIfYes -- move the event listeners to the root level of your javascript. Shouldn't affect performance. See my answer below, working fine.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a glitch in the way you define the function -- by calling checkIfYes() it's looking for it on the global (window's) scope. By changing the line:

```
function checkIfYes() {...
```

to this:

```
checkIfYes = function() {...
```

then you've got it on the global scope. Which is, by the way, bad practice. You'd be better to create a click handler in your script itself, than to hard- code the function call in your HTML. But that's just me.

A few changes made, some pretty significant -- first, I removed the hard-coded reference to checkIfYes and simply put the event in your javascript. Second (and pretty darn significant), I moved the event handlers to the root of your javascript, rather than defining them in your checkIfYes function. This way, they don't depend on that being called each time. Try it, it works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /**
   *  Define some custom events to handle...
   **/
      $("#defect").on("change", checkIfYes );
  // show user if their input is one of the codes in the array when leaving field
      $('#auth_code_input').blur(function() {
        if (!ValidateInput()) {
          console.log("Input is wrong!");
        }
      });
      // prevent form submission if input is not one of the codes in the array
      $('#auth_form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("This is where I would be checking...");
        if (ValidateInput()) {
          $("#auth_form").submit();
        }
      });
  
 
  // Utility Functions.
  function checkIfYes() {
    if (document.getElementById('defect').value == 'Yes') {

      // show extra fields & make them required
      document.getElementById('extra').style.display = '';
      document.getElementById('auth_code_input').disabled = false;
      document.getElementById('desc').disabled = false;

    } else { // hide and disable extra fields so form can submit
      document.getElementById('extra').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('auth_code_input').disabled = true;
      document.getElementById('desc').disabled = true;
    }
  }
  
        function ValidateInput() {
        var codes = ['Foo', 'Bar']; // user must enter one of these
        var IsValid = false;
        var input = $('#auth_code_input').val()

        if (codes.indexOf(input) > -1) { // if input equals one of the codes in the array
          $('#iconBad').removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
          IsValid = true;
        } else {
          $('#iconBad').removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
          IsValid = false;
        }

        return IsValid;
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" method="post" action="action.php">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Defect?</label>
    <select class="select form-control" id="defect" name="defect">
      <option id="No" value="No">No</option>
      <option id="Yes" value="Yes">Yes</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="extra" name="extra" style="display: none">

    <label class="control-label" for="desc">Description</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="desc" name="desc" required disabled>

    <label class="control-label" for="auth_by">Authorised By</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="auth_code_input" name="auth_by" required disabled>

  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">Submit
    </button>
  </div>

</form>
```